# Why operation Rationalize doesn't happen for all elements of the list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to rewrite the list `a` in the form which consist only rational numbers.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
a = {0.026284, 0.0417685, 0.1981855, 0.271658, 988.306428, 4689.34999,
    10214.64282} // Rationalize

Out[348]= {6571/250000, 83537/2000000, 0.198186, 135829/500000, 
988.306, 4689.35, 10214.6}
```

Why operation Rationalize doesn't happen for all elements of the list  `a` ?

Comment: other things to try is `Rationalize[a,0]` and `SetAccuracy[a,Infinity]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the second argument of Rationalize to control the rationalization process, for instance

```
Rationalize[a, 0.001]
```

will rationalize all elements of a to an accuracy of 0.001. The Details section of the help file explains that the default value is 10^-4, so when there is no rational closer than the specified value, it returns the value unchanged.

Comment: “No rational closer than the specified value”?? (I know that’s not what you meant.)

Comment: Details says it properly. The value is not changed if: "there is no rational number close enough to x to satisfy the condition |p/q-x|<c/q^2, with c chosen to be 10^-4." We love our help files!

Answer (score 5):

Use [`SetPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision.html) to turn machine numbers into rationals with exactly same value:

```
a = {0.026284, 0.0417685, 0.1981855, 0.271658, 988.306428, 
     4689.34999, 10214.64282} // SetPrecision[#, ∞] &

(*    {7575847206771591/288230376151711744, 3009737616573193/72057594037927936,
       7140385151601883/36028797018963968, 4893755470288857/18014398509481984,
       8693235275134113/8796093022208, 5155994840716269/1099511627776,
       5615559277084315/549755813888}                                          *)
```